Convert PDF to Excel in Java Spring Boot 3.x +
I have a new task about Converting pdf file to Excel file using Spring Boot framework.
If any one suggest me the maven dependency and Code, It will be much help for me.
        @PostMapping("/convert")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> convert(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile pdfFile) throws IOException {
        
        // Code will be here for Converting Pdf to Excel.
        
        return null;
    }


Your problem has nothing to do with Spring Boot. You'd solve it the same way if you were using a plain Java console application.

Check this: Java: Convert PDF to Excel

Okay, thank you.
But have any way to fix this issue?
@MarkRotteveel have you suggest me something?

There is a library called Aspose that does this here. Here's some example code that might work
Document doc = new Document(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfFile.getBytes()));
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
doc.save(output, SaveFormat.EXCEL);

Note: This code was written of the top of my head from my phone so it might need some fixing.
